# Como encontrar um determinado valor em uma linha que contém uma palavra-chave - python

Tags: python

Como eu poderia achar um valor em uma determinada linha que contenha uma palavra chave

Exemplo (Esse é o arquivo Espelho)

> ```
>  COTIA CENTRO
> ```
>
> EXTRATO         05978754
>
> ITEM 1 ITEM 2 ITEM 3
>
> OPR: 082545444

Eu gostaria de saber como encontrar esse valor do que está a frente do extrato , Exemplo

Se o número tal estiver na mesma linha do Extrato ele retorna verdadeiro , se não estiver retorna falso

Esse é meu código

```
import re
import json
import os
import os.path
from time import sleep

with open('P:/portal/cupons/API/valores_api.json', 'r') as jsonFileLeitura:
    dadosJson = json.load(jsonFileLeitura)
    valor = dadosJson['valor']


def procura_cupom():
    txt = open("P:/portal/cupons/Arquivos_Espelho/arqEspelho.txt", "r").read()

    # usando finditer ele retorna a posição da palavra

    # Localiza o inicio do cupom
    x = re.finditer(r".*COTIA CENTRO", txt)
    # Localiza o fim do cupom
    z = re.finditer(r"OPR.*", txt)

    espelhos = list(zip(x, z))

    # Testando o valor específico para cada espelho
    for espelho in espelhos:

        txt_espelho = txt[espelho[0].span()[0]: espelho[1].span()[1] + 1]

        if "{}".format(valor) in txt_espelho:
            if os.path.isfile("P:/portal/cupons/Arquivos_Espelho/espelhado.txt"):
                open("P:/portal/cupons/Arquivos_Espelho/espelhado.txt", 'w').close()
            sleep(1)
            # Escreve o Cupom caso encontrado, em um novo arquivo de texto
            open("P:/portal/cupons/Arquivos_Espelho/espelhado.txt", "w+").write(txt_espelho)

        else:
            pass


if True:
    procura_cupom()
```

Obrigado!

Answer (score 0):

Se o arquivo estiver apenas com a linha neste formato: "EXTRATO 05978754"

É só ler o arquivo linha a linha:

```
import re

for linha in open("P:/portal/cupons/Arquivos_Espelho/arqEspelho.txt", "r").readLines():
    if "EXTRATO" in linha.split():
       if re.match(r'^([\s\d]+)$', linha):
          return True
```